# Matlab cannot find the mpeg codec on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, video, matlab, codecs

I have MATLAB(64 bit) 2011a and Ubuntu 16.04.

When I try to execute the following MATLAB command-

```
v=VideoReader('demo.mp4');
```

I get the following error -

```
------------

    ??? The file requires the following codec(s) to be installed on your system: video/mpeg

------------

Error in ==> VideoReader.VideoReader>VideoReader.init at 423
            obj.VideoReaderImpl = audiovideo.mmreader(fullName);

Error in ==> VideoReader.VideoReader>VideoReader.VideoReader at 133
            obj.init(fileName);

------------
```

I do have all the codecs installed and I have installed the Ubuntu Restricted Extras.

The Totem player is able to play the video file, so it looks as if the MATLAB is not able to find the codec or may be it requires 64 bit codecs. Where do i find 64 bit mpeg codec?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1246784.

Comment: Try the solution in the last post [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/250220-matlab-cannot-find-codecs-on-linux?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com&nocookie=true).

Comment: @luchonacho: Thank you for your comment. However, i have already tried this solution and it does not resolve my issue. I have installed gstreamer0.10 already. The bad,ugly,good and base plugins do not have an installable any more. So i downloaded them from the source and installed them. However it does not solve the issue. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by -

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

The latest repository library "ffmpeg" does not have the codecs needed by my system and i had to install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg (not in the repository) from the ppa.